# Files starting with + reveal inconsistencies in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I am having trouble understanding why file names starting with the character + cause problems in Linux (I am using LUbuntu 14.04 and bash with lxterminal). Here is my problem:

I can create a file named `+1`:

```
$ touch +1
```

I can even write to it:

```
$ echo "Up-voted!" | cat > +1
```

And I can edit it:

```
$ sed -i "s/Up/Down/" +1
```

I can read from it:

```
$ cat +1
```

But not with `less`:

```
$ less +1
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
```

The command `more` seems to give a hint, since it actually interprets +NUM as an option string (start at line NUM):

```
$ more +1 -2 ~/sample.py 
#!/bin/python
import numpy as np
```

`vim` behaves the same as `more` (isn't that sweet! ) (sorry, I did NOT try `emacs`)

At least `nano` and `leafpad` work (though I am perfectly happy to use `sed` or cosmic particle beams to edit my files ._. ).

Are there any other such "quirks"?

Comment: This is not really a problem, so much as it is simply that some programs are interpreting the `+` to mean something.  You can probably do `less -- +1`

Comment: Did you try `man less` or read the documentation of `less` (e.g. its [FAQ](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html)...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`less` treats arguments starting with `+` as options, not as filenames.  To use less on a file whose name starts with `+`, either escape the `+` or use the `--` argument first (eg, `less -- +1`).

There are plenty of similar quirks, whenever a file name uses a character with special meaning to the shell or on a tool's command line.  Escaping the character is always a solution; many tools that have characters with special meaning in their command lines accept the `--` argument to indicate that everything following is a file name.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options.

You can use the `--` cli separator (as others have already suggested):

```
less -- +1
```

or include file's relative directory (i.e. `.`) in pointing the command to the file:

```
less ./+1
```

(btw, I don't see what kind of escaping can help here)

Answer (score 2):

Less actually uses + as an operator.

From the man less:

-+     Followed  by  one  of  the command line option letters this will
              reset the option to its default  setting  and  print  a  message
              describing  the  new  setting.  (The "-+X" command does the same
              thing as "-+X" on the command line.)  This  does  not  work  for
              string-valued options.

So you need to escape + as follows: 
less -- +1 
This (the --)  tells less (and vim) to ignore options.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but if you look carefully, the portion of the man you referenced deals with "+" **preceded** by a "-" which is different than a single "+". However, I found the relevant bit of the manual discussing a leading "+" in particular:


`+cmd   Causes  the specified cmd to be executed each time a new file is examined.  For example, +G causes less to initially display each file starting at the end rather than the beginning.`

Answer (score 1):

Because `less` consider `+1` as pattern or command argument. It fails to consider it as a file.

To make `less` command to view `+1` as file, you need to give the full path of `+1` file in the less command.

```
less /path/+1
```